# Cannot find symbol saying Implemented interface not found

Tags: java

I developed  very basic java interface(code 1.) named Printable and a java class named HighPrint (Code 2)which Implements the Printable interface and override the relevant methods. Interface developed in source file called Printable.java and class developed in source file HighPrint.java. I compiled the Printable.java successfully. But When I try to compile the HighPrint.java  it gives a compile error as follow.

```
ERROR
======
java:2:cannot find symbol 
symbol:class Printable
public class HighPrint implements Printable {
                              ^
```

Following shows the codes

```
//Code 1 

package printing;

interface Printable{
  public void print(String val);
}

//Code 2

package printing;
import printing.Printable;
public class HighPrint implements Printable {
  public void printX(){
    System.out.print("X");
  }
}
```

Please Note that I am using the windows 7 64 bit OS, jre 7, jdk 1.6.0_23 and java update 7

Comment: You need to override the method in the interface. The current `print` in your `HighPrint` doesn't overrride the `print` present in the `Printable` interface - **Signature mismatch**.

Comment: What is the point of getting that error?

Comment: @nikpon  when compiling , second and 3rd line of Code 2.
near the Printable @ import statement and implementation statement

Comment: @Alya'aGamal How Come It...? Any way you have to import in to source file event they are belongs to same package.

Answer (score 3):

A few things:

1. Set classpath properly so compiler can
   see and compile all classes
2. You must `override` all methods specified in the `interface`

**Working example:**

```
package printing;

interface Printable {
    public void print(String val);
}

package printing;

public class HighPrint implements Printable {

    @Override
    public void print(String val) {
        System.out.print("X");

    }
}
```

Comment: Both source in same directory as D:\JavaProject\Basic\Printable.java
D:\JavaProject\Basic\HighPrint.java

Comment: @Lasan Override print(String val) method properly

Comment: @Lasan @JSS BTW, the interface declares `print(String val)`, not `printX`.

Comment: @michaelb958 Agreed. Sorry copy/paste.

Comment: @JSS and michaelb968 done as you mension but still having the problem

Comment: @Lasan make sure you followed all the steps I mentioned. No typo etc. Finally paste your code here.

Comment: @JSS     package printing;
//import printing.Printable;
public class HighPrint {

public void print(){
System.out.print("X");
}
}  After this Its compiled , that means there is no issue with class path , But it does'nt sort out my issue. When I add the import statement and Interface implementation still coming the error.

Comment: @Lasan your java files are placed in wrong folder it seems. As you mentioned D:\JavaProject\Basic\Printable.java D:\JavaProject\Basic\HighPrint.java, these should be in printing folder, then only you can use `package printing`. Move your file from Basic to Basic\printing folder.

Comment: @harsh it's a very good observation. I was assuming he has already done the basic things :)

Comment: @harsh and JSS I did as your advice but problem still continuing .